# Why I can't delete Link between person and group identities with Platform of Trust's Identity API?

Tags: api, platform, platform-of-trust

I have created account on [Sandbox](https://world-sandbox.oftrust.net/)

I have then created a group with

```
curl -i -X POST \
   -H "Authorization: Bearer <ACCESS_TOKEN>" \
   -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
   -d \
"{
  \"context\": \"https://standards.oftrust.net/v2/Context/Identity/Group/\",
  \"type\": \"Group\",
  \"data\": {
    \"name\": \"Company Oy\"
  }
}" "https://api-sandbox.oftrust.net/identities/v1"
```

I have also created a Link between person and group, I used `MemberOf`

```
curl -i --request POST \
  --url https://api-sandbox.oftrust.net/identities/v1/{fromIdentityId}/link/{toIdentityId} \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer <ACCESS_TOKEN>' \
  --header 'content-type: application/json' \
  --data '{
  "context": "https://standards.oftrust.net/v2/Context/Link/Role/MemberOf/",
  "type": "Member"
}'
```

I got successful response that link was created between those identities.

Trying to delete this link now, but I get as response **404** and message **Link not found.**

What I try is according with example from [documentation](https://docs.oftrust.net/?shell#identities-v1-from_identity-link-to_identity-type)

```
curl -i -X DELETE \
   -H "Authorization: Bearer <ACCESS_TOKEN>" \
 "https://api-sandbox.oftrust.net/identities/v1/{fromIdentityId}/link/{toIdentityId}/MemberOf"
```

[UPDATE]: I discovered also in [Identity API documentation](https://docs.oftrust.net/?shell#identities-v1-id-links) that can list all links of identity.
And have made this for group identity:

```
curl -i -X GET \
   -H "Authorization: Bearer <ACCESS_TOKEN>" \
 "https://api-sandbox.oftrust.net/identities/v1/<group_id>/links"
```

The response shows that link between group and person identities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, make sure you respected the id values (their order) for From and To. They should be the same you get in response of `https://api-sandbox.oftrust.net/identities/v1/<group_id>/links`

Secondly, delete Link endpoint needs to be used with a type, as exemplified. In this case `MemberOf`. But looking at the creation of the link there is a typo: context used is correct, but the type is `Member`. Type should match the last part of the name in context => `MemberOf`

In this case, since you are trying to delete it, simply use Member

```
curl -i -X DELETE \
   -H "Authorization: Bearer <ACCESS_TOKEN>" \
 "https://api-sandbox.oftrust.net/identities/v1/{fromIdentityId}/link/{toIdentityId}/Member"
```